# May I use OR to check if my default value is necessary?

Tags: python, coding-style

Instead of

```
if foo is None:
    foo = 'my-default'
```

I write

```
foo = foo or 'my-default'
```

because it's shorter. Is the latter one against some recommendations or may I run into serious problems using the `OR` operator to save one line? Or is it really unreadable? Or something else really bad or evil?

I think it's really more readable, especially if you have

```
if not foo:
    foo = 1
if not bar:
    bar = 2
if not uhj:
    uhj = 3
```

I just write

```
foo = foo or 1
bar = bar or 2
uhj = uhj or 3
```

I think, that's easier

Comment: It's quite common practice. Just be aware that if `foo` can be a falsy value this won't work.

Comment: The question is not opinion based because - as you can see - THEY ARE conditions my code may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent because the first one is selective to the value `None` while the second one performs a general truth-test. So for example for `foo=0` or `foo=[]` only the second one will replace it with `'my-default'`. You could make the first one equivalent to the second:

```
if not foo:
    foo = 'my-default'
```

Other than that I think both of them are fine. Some people advocate against the the second choice because it might confuse beginners. But IMHO it is a common pattern in python and it can be more readable, so I think it is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the statement

```
foo = foo or 'my-default'
```

the default is given for every false value of foo, not only None. If that is appropriate then I think that this one-liner is better then the 'if'. It sounds comprehensible also if you read it as a natural language.